# Unable to upload multiple images - Springboot

Tags: image, spring-boot, arraylist, file-upload

I'm trying to upload multiple images in Springboot.

Here is my form HTML:

```
<form th:action="@{${#httpServletRequest.requestURI}}" th:object="${formInput}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

To take in multiple files:

```
<input type="file" onclick="radioButton()"  onchange=" enableSubmit();" id = "fileInput" name="uploadingFiles[]" accept="image/*" multiple/>
```

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userProfiles/{userId}/setup/Tool.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void makeIAmVideo(@PathVariable Long userId, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam(value = "track_value") int trackNumber, @RequestParam("uploadingFiles") MultipartFile[] uploadingFiles) throws IOException {
    UserProfile userProfile = userProfileRepository.findById(userId);
    ArrayList<String> photos = new ArrayList<>();
    String audioPath= audioPath1;
    System.out.println(trackNumber);
    for(MultipartFile file : uploadingFiles){
        photos.add(file.getName());
    }
 }
```

But when I debug it, the photos are not uploaded in the photos array list, it's size stays 0.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add these line in your form which contain this input field.

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: I actually have this in the form tag:
 <form th:action="@{${#httpServletRequest.requestURI + '?update=true'}}" th:object="${formInput}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">